# iOS Launcscreen storyboard image doesn't load immediatly

Tags: ios, xcode

Note: this is on a react-native app, but the launch screen is on the xcode side so the issue should relate to native iOS.

Our launchscreen has an image in the center rendered through a `UIImageView`.

I've saved the image in the `xcassets`, its size is small and I've tried svg, jpeg and png files.

No matter what when the launchscreen shows up, the image takes too much time to appear. If I add other elements in the view controller like a `UILabel` they show up immediatly.

How can I have the image render immediatly ?

Here's a video

[image]

https://streamable.com/pnak13

Comment: Did you previously install the app with a launch screen that didn't have the image?  It looks like iOS is showing its saved snapshot (which is just the blue screen with the text) and then showing your new launch screen.  Delete the app entirely from the device/simulator and run it again.

Comment: I've come to identify that pattern that deleting the app seems to fix it, but then it seems to do that bug again some short time after.

Comment: Yes. Don't worry about it. The behaviour you see during development is different to when the app is released. Most of the time in release mode you will never see the launch screen anyway